# Facebook App Privacy Policy Error

Tags: facebook

guys. I'm trying to publish a game on Facebook but i have to provide a link to my App's Privacy Policy. I have a website that contains a webpage that contains that privacy policy. When i add the link to Facebook I get the below massage. My website is hosted by GoDaddy.com. I remember a day when go daddy accepted emails, which was much convenient then phone calls simply because not everyone can afford it.
Can you please help me figure out what to do? I tried adding a webpage from another website Facebook accepted it. We added some `Meta Tags`, but nothing worked.
The URL to the Webpage is: http://fueltanklab.com/games/touchball/privacypolicy

> You must submit a valid Privacy Policy URL in order to be compliant
>   with Facebook Platform. Request failed with error: Could Not Connect
>   To Server: Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no
>   firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the server's IP. GoDaddy.com uses Virtual Hosting where they use the same IP for many websites. For some reason the IP that they gave us had some problems or maybe some website that we share the IP with is blocked or has a bad reputation (I'm not sure of the reason). So I took a dedicated IP for my website and now everything is working as it should.